# how to remove multiple back button from navigation in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

please help me to sort out following issue.

this is my issue.if push without animation(false)then issue.if animation true then working fine.

```
//  await Navigation.PushAsync<DeleteDealsAndOffersViewModel>(); --> **working fine**

//  await Navigation.PushAsync(new DeleteDealsAndOffersViewModel());**working fine** 


vm = new DeleteDealsAndOffersViewModel
            {
                DealsAndOffersList = dealLists,
                //CategoryColor = CategoryColor,
                IsDelete = true
            };

//await Navigation.PushAsync(vm,false); **issue with back button**
```

[image]

I have used following code for back button.this is my base class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v:ExtendedContentPage 
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Core.Views;assembly=Core" 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    LeftBarButtonTitle="&lt; Back"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Vi.Views.BasicV">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</v:ExtendedContentPage>

now I create another page and set base class on that page
```

**DeleteDealsAndOffersListPage.xaml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <view:BasicV 
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Vi.Views;assembly=FlagSpree" 
        xmlns:sty="clr-namespace:VillageVesl.Styles;assembly=FlagSpree" 
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Core.Views;assembly=Core" 
        xmlns:comp="clr-namespace:VillageVesl.Views.Components;assembly=FlagSpree" 
        x:Name="main" Title="{Binding Title}"
        LeftBarButtonTitle="Cancel"
        BackgroundColor="{x:Static sty:Colors.BGColor}"
        x:Class="Vi.Views.DeleteDealsAndOffersListPage">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem IsDestructive="true" Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteAllSelectedDealsCommand}" />
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
      <ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </view:BasicV>
```

**"DeleteDealsAndOffersListPage.xaml.cs"**.

```
namespace Vi.Views
{
    public partial class DeleteDealsAndOffersListPage : BasicV
    {
        public DeleteDealsAndOffersListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now problem is that when I push on **DeleteDealsAndOffersListPage** then display two back button.

Comment: What do you mean it displays two back button? It has 2 back buttons one under the other or you have 2 pages from which you have to go back 2 times? I would check that you're not using differents NavigationPage's but the same one across the whole application

Comment: I have create on page for navigation title and back button and use in create page class.when i push navigation using animation working fine but when animation is false. it display to button.

Comment: Assuming Navigation is INavigation, page and viewModel are two different things; pages can be pushed onto the navigation stack using Navigation.PushAsync, viewModels can be bound (set to) to the BindingContext property of a page, more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating your own Back Button.  Xamarin will add it's own back button to any page that you push onto a Navigation stack, is that the extra back button you are seeing?  If so, before you do the push, add:

```
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(vm, false);
```

Comment: vm is model.not page